# Page crash when trying to add tag

Tags: bug, status-norepro, tags, editing

I am trying to edit [this](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/290532/104387) post, adding the `pt` tag. I can open the edit window just fine, but once I type in "pt" into the tag field, the page locks up. Typing in "p" works fine, but adding the "t" crashes it. I tried adding the tag on other questions and it does the same.

EDIT: After letting the page load for a while, this happens.

[image]

Note the length of the page on the scroll bar.

Comment: I was able to successfully edit in the tag without having the issues you mentioned. Do you use any userscripts?

Comment: Browser is up to date, as arda mentioned, any userscripts and the like, faulty/out of date plugins, bad extensions, anything? I could also edit the page without issues.

Comment: Hi @rivermont-WillB. is this still happening?

Comment: Given that noone else has had this issue in the two years since this report, I think we can consider this as [status-norepro]